# How to install KDESvn on Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, svn

[KDESvn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDESvn) is not any more in the list of supported packages for **Ubuntu 16.10**. Is it still possible somehow to install it?

Comment: For some reason it was removed from repos quite a long time ago. I'd recommend to search for deb packages in debian repositories.